# Intel Pin: how to obtain return address of system call

Tags: c++, intel-pin

In Intel Pin you can get the return address of a routine call using `IARG_RETURN_IP` as one of the arguments of `RTN_InsertCall`.

I wanted to do the same with a system call, instrumented using `PIN_AddSyscallEntryFunction` and `PIN_AddSyscallExitFunction`.

So at first I thought about getting the value of the instruction pointer after the call using 
`ADDRINT returnIp = PIN_GetContextReg(ctx, REG_INST_PTR);`in the function passed as argument to `PIN_AddSyscallExitFunction`.

However, I noticed that, if I get the value of `REG_INST_POINTER` in the same way but this time before the system call is executed, I always get the same two values for the instruction pointer.

For example, I would always get 2003266482 before and 2003266484 after.

So I was wondering why is this the case and if I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with the way system calls are executed in libc, there is a single assembly stub that actually does what needs to be done to pass control from and back to the kernel, which all system calls go through.